# WSO2 - How to create a SOAP webservice?

Tags: web-services, soap, wso2

I want to create a new SOAP webservice to recieve request from other parties.
How to create it from scratch using WSO2 ?

Comment: Please refer the WSO2 documentation so that you will get an idea on the intention of WSO2 productions and how you can use it. Specially WSO2 API Manager and WSO2 EI.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't find anything of help, and that's why the question posted here.

Comment: I found that using APIM or EI we can create proxy service to extend and existing web service. But my ask is about how to create that initial web service in WSO2.

Comment: WSO2 products are providing you middleware to facilitate your web service. You cannot use a middleware to create the service.

Comment: Ok, fine. Thank you for the responses. Much appreciated.